# Does IE 11 support deep cloneNode?

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, clonenode, internet-explorer-11

In IE up until version 10, deep cloning of nodes using `cloneNode` is not supported.

For IE I am using `innerHTML` for cloning. Will `cloneNode(true)` work in IE 11?

Is this supported in IE 11?

(I have no way to test this)

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell using [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uFeralI/2/edit), deep clones (`.cloneNode(true)`) are supported in IE8, IE9, IE10 and IE11.

Additionally, it looks like IE7 supports deep node clones too, as [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6vAe/embedded/result/) demonstrates (couldn't get JSBin working in IE7).

The following code creates to lines of text with the contents shown below.

#### HTML snippet

```
<div id="cloneTarget">
    <span>A child element <em>With some italic text</em></span>
    <strong>Another child here</strong>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
var cloned = document.getElementById('cloneTarget').cloneNode(true);

document.body.appendChild(cloned);
```

#### Expected output:

> A child element *With some italic text* **Another child here**
>   A child element *With some italic text* **Another child here**

Comment: CloneNode appears not to work for SVG elements.  IE 11 says the function is undefined.